# power query (M) create record from a text type column

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

when retrieving data from a web based API into the Power BI, I did end up with a quoted record (text type) which I am unable to convert to a record. There must be a simple way to do this, unfortunately I was not able to find it.

So simply `record = [A=1,B=2]` is implicitly detected, if written like this `record = "[A=1,B=2]"` you end up with a text, which needs to be converted. What function can do this kind of conversion?

This is the result similar to the API, which will require transformation on the entire column.

```
let
    Source = {"[A=1, B=1, C=0, D=1]","[A=1, B=1, C=0, D=1]"},
    Table = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error)
in
    Table
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Expression.Evaluate:

```
let
    Source = {"[A=1, B=1, C=0, D=1]","[A=1, B=1, C=0, D=1]"},
    Table = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    Evaluate = Table.AddColumn(Table, "Custom", each Expression.Evaluate([Column1]))
in
    Evaluate
```

Comment: Wow - who knew? Amazingly poor documentation of the Expression.Evaluate function, so great work Marcel!